# regular expression to extract information in shell script

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

I would to grep certain parts of some shell command output in the shell script:

```
$ uname -r
>> 3.14.37-1-lts
```

Where I just need the `3.14.37`.

And also for the shell script variable `VERSION` that has the value "-jwl35", I would like to take only the value "jwl35".

How can I use regular expression to this in shell script?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Many, many ways. Here are a few:

1. GNU Grep

   ```
   $ echo 3.14.37-1-lts | grep -oP '^[^-]*'
   3.14.37
   ```
2. `sed`

   ```
   $ echo 3.14.37-1-lts | sed 's/^\([^-]*\).*/\1/'
   3.14.37
   ```
3. Perl

   ```
   $ echo 3.14.37-1-lts | perl -lne '/^(.*?)-/ && print $1
   3.14.37
   ```

   or

   ```
   $ echo 3.14.37-1-lts | perl -lpe 's/^(.*?)-.*/$1/'
   3.14.37
   ```

   or

   ```
   $ echo 3.14.37-1-lts | perl -F- -lane 'print $F[0]'
   3.14.37
   ```
4. awk

   ```
   $ echo 3.14.37-1-lts | awk -F- '{print $1}'
   3.14.37
   ```
5. `cut`

   ```
   $ echo 3.14.37-1-lts | cut -d- -f1
   3.14.37
   ```
6. Shell, even!

   ```
   $ echo 3.14.37-1-lts | while IFS=- read a b; do echo "$a"; done
   3.14.37
   ```

Comment: what is the purpose of "-oP" in "grep -oP" ?

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred, "-o" is for printing only the matching part and "-P" is to use the Perl regex pattern. You can check for "man grep" for details

Comment: ok , got it, so without -o the whole line is shown , with -o only the substring that matches it.

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred exactly. It's a neat way to only print the relevant parts of a line.

Comment: Could you explain the shell option ? What is happening with a and b ?

Answer (score 2):

One approach not covered by [terdon's comprehensive answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193225/6761) is Bash's [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073?action=show&redirect=ParameterExpansion) (which requires no additional process):

```
vers=$(uname -r) && printf "%s\n" "${vers%%-*}"
3.14.37

vers="-jwl35" && printf "%s\n" "${vers#*-}"
jwl35
```